# Visualizing kinect data on rviz

Tags: ros, kinect

I am a beginner of ROS, Kinect and Ubuntu. What I want is to visualize Kinect's data on rviz environment then run object recognition on it.

I've tried a few tutorials but had no luck. All I got was an empty rviz world.

Since I am a beginner I would appreciate any step-by-step instructions (preferably for hydro or groovy).

I would also like to note that I've managed to get visual from Kinect so the device is working fine.

Comment: For ROS-related questions, [its QA forum](http://answers.ros.org/) is the best place to ask question like this.

Comment: @IsaacS While I appreciate that you are trying to help user2433 get his/her question answered, this sort of suggestion isn't terribly useful here and at best it should be a comment. It certainly shouldn't be an answer unless you can provide a link to a QA forum thread which already answers the question. Even then you should provide enough context such that link rot couldn't render the answer invalid.

Comment: the problem is, Rviz works with a time vector besides the image stream that it is receiving. If you are just plugged the kinect to rviz it is normal that it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  install the a package for kinect:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch
```

Then to make the package publish kinect's topics:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

To visualize the depth image run:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth/image
```

To visualize for example the Point Cloud in rviz you can add a PointCloud2 Display ad choose the appropriate topic.

Answer (score -1):

ROS Indigo Igloo will be coming out in a week or 2. Will be the first release in a year (they used to have 6 month release cycle, it has been a long wait). It moves at such a fast pace, so it may be worth waiting until it comes out so you don't have to set up your environment/re-learn new stuff again.

I would recommend you start with MoveIt, even if you already have Hydro or Groovy set up:
http://moveit.ros.org/documentation/tutorials/

With this tutorial first:
http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/moveit_setup_assistant/html/doc/tutorial.html

Then move onto the integrating the Kinect:
http://docs.ros.org/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/perception_configuration.html